# Can't set ImageView photo from datainputstream JavaFx socket application

Tags: java, image, sockets, javafx-2

I am trying to output an image to an ImageView in javafx, i am recieving the image via socket connection and saving it to my hard-drive then i create an Image object with the path of the newly created image, the problem is that the image view is not updated.

```
public void save(String path, DataInputStream dis) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("src/img"+(frame_number)+".jpg");


    //Image imBuff = ImageIO.read(socket.getInputStream());

    int filesize = dis.readInt(); // Send file size in separate msg
    byte[] buffer = new byte[filesize];
    int read = 0;
    int totalRead = 0;
    int remaining = filesize;
    while ((read = dis.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(buffer.length, remaining))) >= 1) {
        totalRead += read;
        remaining -= read;
        //System.out.println("read " + totalRead + " bytes.");
        fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        System.err.println("img"+(frame_number)+".jpg");
        fos.flush();
    }
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();

    System.out.println("frame num:"+frame_number);
    Image i = new Image("Camera_Frame.jpg");
    try{
    //i=new Image("img"+frame_number+".jpg");
        File f = new File("img"+frame_number+".jpg");
        i = new Image(f.toURI().toString());
        iv.setImage(i);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("didn't find");
    }
    System.out.println("stream size:"+image_Stream.size());
    ps.println("ok");
    frame_number++;
}
```

Things i have tried: 
1- i tried to used the path i saved the photo in to create an Image then used the setImage() function on my ImageView (iv), i got Invalid Url even though i loaded an image image from the same directory before. 
2- we tried using (file:///) to get an absolute path but it didn't work, also invalid url 
3- i tried loading the image as a file first then using the toURI() function to get the proper path to it then create an image accordingly, i don't get an error but it also doesn't update the UI

P.S
this function is called in a sub Thread that updates an ImageView in the main javafx thread, i tried it with images not loaded through the socket connection and it worked, but when i try to display the images i receive the face this problem.

EDIT: I managed to load the image properly, now i can't update the ImageView using iv.setImage()

EDIT: 
CameraOBJ class 
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintStream;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.Queue;
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class CameraOBJ implements Runnable{
    String name;
    int delay;

    Socket socket;
    String ip;
    int port;
    PrintStream ps;
    Scanner sc;
    static int frame_number;

    StackPane sp;
    Label delay_lbl;
    ImageView iv;

    public CameraOBJ (String name, String ip, int port){
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        this.name = name;
        sp = new StackPane();
    }

    public void run() {
        setStackPane();
        connect();
        while(true){
            update();
        }
//      Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
//      Duration duration = Duration.seconds(1/Settings.FPS);
//      KeyFrame f1 = new KeyFrame(duration,e->{
//          update();
//      });
//      timeline.getKeyFrames().add(f1);
//      timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
//      timeline.play();
    }

    private void update() {
//      Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { 
//          public void run() {
                DataInputStream dis;
                try {
                    dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    if(dis!=null){
                        save("images",dis);
                        //setStackPane();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
                }
//          }
//      }); 
    }

    public void setStackPane(){
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
                sp.setMinSize(500, 384);
                sp.setMaxSize(500, 384);
                sp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;");
                Image image = new Image("Camera_Frame.jpg");
                iv = new ImageView(image);
                iv.setFitWidth(470);
                iv.setPreserveRatio(true);
                Label name_lbl = new Label(name);
                delay_lbl = new Label(delay+"");

                sp.setAlignment(iv,Pos.CENTER);
                sp.setAlignment(name_lbl,Pos.TOP_LEFT);
                sp.setAlignment(delay_lbl,Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);

                sp.getChildren().addAll(iv,name_lbl,delay_lbl);                
            }
        });
    }

    public void connect(){
        try{   
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            System.out.println(socket.isConnected());

            ps = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            sc = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        }
        catch (Exception c){
            c.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public void save(String path, DataInputStream dis) throws IOException {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream("src/img"+(frame_number)+".jpg");
                int filesize;
                try {
                    filesize = dis.readInt();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[filesize];
                    int read = 0;
                    int totalRead = 0;
                    int remaining = filesize;
                    while ((read = dis.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(buffer.length, remaining))) >= 1) {
                        totalRead += read;
                        remaining -= read;
                        //System.out.println("read " + totalRead + " bytes.");
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        System.err.println("img"+(frame_number)+".jpg");
                        fos.flush();
                    }
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } 
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        System.out.println("frame num:"+frame_number);
        Image i = new Image("Camera_Frame.jpg");
        try{
            //i=new Image("file:img"+frame_number+".jpg");


            File f = new File("C:\\Users\\ahmed\\workspace\\College\\RTS_Client\\src\\img"+frame_number+".jpg");
            i = new Image(f.toURI().toString());
            iv.setImage(i);
            delay_lbl.setText("frame_number: "+frame_number);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("didn't find");
        }

        frame_number++;
        }

        }); 
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import com.sun.prism.paint.Color;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;


public class main extends Application{
    static Stage window;
    static String default_ip = "192.168.43.200";
    static int default_port = 1234;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        window = stage;
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setTitle("Control Room");

        StackPane sp = new StackPane();
        sp.setMinSize(500, 500);
        Scene sc = new Scene(sp);

        window.setScene(sc);
        window.show();


        CameraOBJ camera = new CameraOBJ("Camera 1", default_ip, default_port);
        Thread t = new Thread(camera);
        camera.run();
        sc = new Scene(camera.sp);
        window.setScene(sc);
    }
}
```

Server class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Camera implements Runnable {

    long timeStamp;
    int delayShift;
    int FPS;
    boolean idle;
    //Control Rooms object here
    int portNumber;
    Socket csocket;

    Camera() {
    }

    Camera(Socket csocket) {
        this.csocket = csocket;
    }

   void startConnection() throws Exception {
        ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(1234);
        System.out.println("Listening");
        while (true) {
            Socket sock = ssock.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected");
            new Thread(new Camera(sock)).start();
        }
    }

    public void run() {//Start Stream
        try {
            PrintStream pstream = new PrintStream(csocket.getOutputStream());
            Scanner inpstream = new Scanner(csocket.getInputStream());

            // Receiving an integer that is sent from the client side.
            int ID = inpstream.nextInt();
            // Generating a reply based on the ID sent from the client.
            String response = "";
            if (ID == 1100) {
                response = "Your name is Mahmoud. \n" + "You are 22 years old.";
            } else {
                response = "No data found matching the ID you entered.";
            }

            // Sending the reply through the OutputStream to the client.
            pstream.println(response);
            pstream.close();
            terminateConnection();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString() + "\nNo data is received.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } catch (Exception c) {
            System.out.println(c.toString());
        }
    }

    void terminateConnection() throws IOException {
        csocket.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Camera cam = new Camera();
        cam.startConnection();
    }

}
```

Comment: "this function is called in a sub Thread that updates an ImageView in the main javafx thread" <= you shouldn't update things which are in an active scene graph from another thread, you should do that via [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).  For requesting debugging assistance you should provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (minimal and complete).

Comment: I have posted a version of my code including on the problematic parts.